# MPMovieplayer now playing issue iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have one view control that consists of MP Movie Player control. This control loads video from url. It loads the video perfectly. When I move to the previous control which has TableView, the audio of the video is played in background prefectly. The control which has a TableView consists of 'Now Playing' button. On pressing of 'Now Playing' the user is moved back to MP Movie Player control. But the problem persist here is that the video is loaded again where it was instead of continuous playing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the current position of the movie from the property currentPlaybackTime while on your TableView. Then when you move to the MP Movie Player control, you need to specify the currentPlaybackTime you had used in the TableView.

Comment: I already did that thing. But I need video to be played continuously when swipe view control without loading video from that time.

Comment: An approach I took was to create a ViewController that has a view container and a hidden view with the MoviePlayer. Now the ViewController can show your tableView in its container. When you choose an item in your tableView rather than doing a segue you just unhide the moviePlayer view and position it how you want. You will need a way to intercept your back button so that it hides the MoviePlayer view and reveals your tableView. This way the movie will be able to keep playing and you can hide and unhide as you need.

Comment: ya its good solution but i can't apply this becoz it will get more time to change UI and Code implement

Comment: The second solution I mentioned worked best for me. A quicker fix for you may be to avoid creating a new ViewController with the container. Instead use your existing tableview, but instead of doing a segue to a new ViewController to play your content, just add a view over your tableView containing the MoviePlayer. But you would still need to intercept the back button to hide the MoviePlayerView if its visible.